# How to link a shared library with undefined symbols on Android?

Tags: android, linker, dlopen

I am currently porting a program from MIPS platform to Android ARM platform. The program has a dynamic plugin, which is a shared so file. The so file will access the main program's functions.

My problem is that how can I get the so file linked with the undefined references?

I Googled and found that there are "-undefined dynamic_lookup" flag on Darwin platform. What is the similar approach for Android native build system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on your Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
```

But you might have problems during runtime if it doesn't find the symbols...

Comment: I accept your answer since it really fix the link problem. However, as you pointed out I got the symbol look up problem at runtime. I know that CMAKE has some ENABLE_EXPORTS option, and I also tried add CFLAGS with -export-dynamic -exported_symbols_list but without any help.

Comment: Also tried LOCAL_LDFLAGS += --export-dynamic --dynamic-linker, still no help

Comment: I also had the same problem and I couldn't figure out how to fix it!